# disappearing navigationbar color in iOS 4.3

Tags: ios, ios4, ios5, tintcolor

I'm setting the `tintColor` of a navigation bar with this command:

```
[self.navigationController.navigationBar setTintColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:0.35 green:0.09 blue:0.2 alpha:1.0]];
```

but in `iOS 4.3` (simulator and phone), the navigation bar is transparent, only showing my custom image and related buttons. in `iOS 5`, this tint is just fine.

Any thoughts on how to fix this for iOS 4.3? The tintcolor is being set in a subclassed BaseViewController

Comment: Same problem with MFMailComposeViewController with iOS 4.3. I used default settings for the MFMailComposeViewController. The bar is missing and the title shows in a hazzy 3D text which is very hard to read.

Comment: Looks like my problems were because I was overriding the UINavigationBar as discussed here: http://foobarpig.com/iphone/uinavigationbar-with-solid-color-or-image-background.html

Comment: you could try setting the translucent or opaque properties, maybe that will help...

Answer (score 1):

I think this problem is there in the older versions of iOS5.0. I am doing the same thing without any issue. I am using iOS Simulator Version 5.0 (272) and Xcode 4.2 Build 4D199

Answer (score 1):

```
its working in ios 6.0


self.navigationController.navigationBar.tintColor=[UIColor colorWithRed:(157/255.0) green:(33/255.0) blue:(33/255.0) alpha:1];
```